# How to use variables in access_log filename with Nginx (healthd)

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services

I have a mutli-container setup in AWS. I'm trying to follow this:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/health-enhanced-serverlogs.html

However (using latest Nginx - 1.9.12) as soon as I try to use variables in the filename I start to see errors in the error log, and the file itself is not created.

error.log:

```
2016/03/10 05:57:38 [error] 6#6: *1 testing "/etc/nginx/html" existence failed (2: No such file or directory) while logging request, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: localhost, request: "GET /v1/service?staus=ok HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8088/v1/service?staus=ok", host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
```

This configuration is not working:

```
upstream app_v1 {
  server app_v1:8088;
}

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default        "upgrade";
  ""            "";
}

log_format healthd '$msec"$uri"'
          '$status"$request_time"$upstream_response_time"'
          '$http_x_forwarded_for';

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

  gzip on;
  gzip_comp_level 4;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

  if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
    set $year $1;
    set $month $2;
    set $day $3;
    set $hour $4;
  }

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;

  location ~* ^/ {
    proxy_pass         http://app_v1;
    proxy_redirect     off;

    proxy_set_header   Connection      $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade         $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

And this one is working fine:

```
upstream app_v1 {
  server app_v1:8088;
}

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default        "upgrade";
  ""            "";
}

log_format healthd '$msec"$uri"'
          '$status"$request_time"$upstream_response_time"'
          '$http_x_forwarded_for';

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

  gzip on;
  gzip_comp_level 4;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log healthd;

  location ~* ^/ {
    proxy_pass         http://app_v1;
    proxy_redirect     off;

    proxy_set_header   Connection      $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade         $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

However the healthd service (enhance health) is looking for a file formatted:

```
/var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour
```

I can reproduce this locally using docker-compose. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Maxime

Comment: While probably not solving your case, `mkdir /etc/nginx/html` should remove the error you're mentionning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a common pitfall. Doc on [`access_log`](http://nginx.org/r/access_log) says:

> The file path can contain variables (0.7.6+), but such logs have some constraints:
>
> - ...
> - during each log write the existence of the request’s **root directory** is checked, and if it does not exist the log is **not created**.

You didn't set root directory so nginx falls back to default one that is `/etc/nginx/html` and it doesn't exists.

Just add `root /var/www;` (or some other existing path) or, as zezollo suggested, create `/etc/nginx/html`.

Comment: I have to say that the debug `error_log` mode is not helping at all...